# How to stabilize my sawtooth oscillator

Tags: oscillator, waveform

I'm experimenting with waveform generation and I'm using the low-voltage op-amps mcp6002, powered by an arduino due with 3.3V, single supply (3.3V-0V).

The circuit i'm using is similar to this one (the op-amps are replaced with mcp6002, and the circuit is working as I describe)

[image]

For the "N-channel enhancement" FET module I use a [ZVN420](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZVN4206A.pdf).

Now everything else in the circuit ( i.e. couple of DACS, another oscillator based on the MCP6002 that produces a triangle and a pulse) are very stable and working succesfully. But my two sawtooth oscillators are very sensitive to the ground and power connections. To make the sawtooth rise curve sharp 
I have to touch the cables in the circuit. After some tries the waveform is perfect but in general very easily it stops forming the right waveform. (it becomes like a sawtooth - triangle).
Can someone guide me how to counter this situation? I have tried replacing all long cables with very small wires but this does not improved the behaviour. The breadboard is very good. I have tried adding capacitors for voltage buffering but I didn't noticed any difference.

Comment: it's like you're trying to build your own LM555

Comment: to understand failure you only need to validate I-O measurements as what you expect for a BJT output stage in the LF411 by reading the specs to get the answer. with a 5Vpp drop , it will never work on 3.3V reliably.

Comment: @Tony Stewart. EE since '75. The schematic I posted is "similar" to the one I'm using. If you read the question I'm using mcp 6002 op-amps which are low voltage and the sawtooth waveform is created fine. The problem is as I describe in the question. (I don't use the op-amps displayed in the schematic. I post this schematic to see the topology of the sawtooth generation.

Comment: ok but read my comment again about measuring inputs and outputs. U1+ is Vdc with same gain on ground signals, U1- is the same voltage, U1out is the -ve sawtooth, U2 is the comparator to Vdd/2 and U2 out is the + pulse that must discharge C with RdsOn before the pulse is turns off ,,so the threshold for U2 and C may have to be reduced or RdsOn reduced for the same T , otherwise it won't reset properly.

Comment: @Tony Stewart. EE since '75 Thank you very much, I will test this tomorrow. (that is exactly what most probably happens, the threshold is too high). Thanks again.

Comment: actually my best guess is C is to big to discharge for a rapid loop delay pulse width, so C  must be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that circuit in your picture supposed to be supplied by a symmetrical +15V and -15V supply?  In that case it will need some adaptation for a single supply. 
The transistor you are using can also have a threshold up to 3V, so you might not even turn it on with a 3.3V supply only.

MAybe this topology helps https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4362

Answer (score 1):

The LF411 data sheet implies that the lowest supply voltage it can effectively operate from is 10 volts. Forget all about trying to get this to run at 3.3 volts.

See figures 3, 4 and 5 of the data sheet. They imply that the lowest positive supply is 5 volts and ditto for the negative supply.

The LM319 can operate from a supply as low as 5 volts. Don't expect miracles.

Comment: Post the correct schematic not some look-alike. Show all supply rails, name components, put values on them and show decoupler capacitors. Also add a picture of your breadboard/prototype.